# while loop calling function but only for first line, Serverlist.txt contains multiple server details

Tags: function, shell, ssh, while-loop

I am trying to catch the log, Serverlist.txt contains some servers details like **root 10.0.0.1 22 TestServer**, while I run the script it only read the first line and exit, its not working for further lines. Below is my script.

```
newdate1=`date -d "yesterday" '+%b %d' | sed 's/0/ /g'`
newdate2=`date -d "yesterday" '+%d/%b/%Y'`
newdate3=`date -d "yesterday" '+%y%m%d'`
DL=/opt/$newdate3
Serverlist=/opt/Serverlist.txt
serverlog()
{
mkdir -p $DL/$NAME
ssh -p$PORT $USER@$IP "cat /var/log/messages*|grep '$newdate1'"|cat > $DL/$NAME/messages.log
}
while read USER IP PORT NAME
do
    serverlog
    sleep 1;
done <<<"$Serverlist"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<` instead of `<<<`. `<<<`is a Here String substitution. The right side is evaluated, and then the result is read from the loop as standard input:

```
$ FILE="my_file"
$ cat $FILE
First line
Last line
$ while read LINE; do echo $LINE; done <$FILE
First line
Last line
$ set -x
$ while read LINE; do echo $LINE; done <<<$FILE
+ read LINE
+ echo my_file
my_file
+ read LINE
$ while read LINE; do echo $LINE; done <<<$(ls /home)
++ ls /home
+ read LINE
+ echo antxon install lost+found
antxon install lost+found
+ read LINE
$
```

Comment: I tried with "<" this also, but its not working, one thing to notice here is I am reading each column instead of line and then I want that column variable to use in function. while I use that as a variable then it run for the first line only.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from another link.

you can use "-n" option in ssh, this will not break the loop and you will get the desired result.